# Unable to get total result count in service now

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am unable to get total result count in service now Rest api. I am creating  query but It return the results .I want to get the results with total result count So that I may implement paging.

https:///api/now/table/kb_knowledge?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the X-Total-Count in the response headers.
According to the documentation (https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/orlando/rest/c_TableAPI), this parameter should only return the count of records for the request you passed.

But from what I am seeing, it always returns total count of records available for that table object.

For instance, your request - `https:///api/now/table/kb_knowledge?sysparm_limit=10&sysparm_offset=0` should result in `X-Total-Count = 10` but it returns the total number of records available for `kb_knowledge` table object.

Comment: Only issue with this answer is that if you are trying to access the X-Total-Count header using any Power Query functions (only applicable to Power Platform and Excel developers) it will be hidden by Microsoft and there is no way to expose it. Using the stats api as noted by Mark Paradis below will get you the count in the response body.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue but if you use the stats API you can use this parameter

https:///api/now/stats/kb_knowledge?sysparm_count=true

you'll get this response

```
{
    "result": {
        "stats": {
            "count": "34"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: This is the secret sauce. Thanks!